# How to join on conditional tables

Tags: mysql, join

I have to maintain a database that has 3 different tables for their users (for different roles). Unfortunately, merging them is not allowed.

There is another table that logs their activity, and this table has two columns for identifying a specific user, one is `userId`, and the other is `roleId`. Now, when I want to list user activities for all users, then depending on the value in `roleId`, I would have to join each row with a different table.

If there was only one table with users, the query would be something like:

```
SELECT * FROM activity JOIN buyers ON activity.userId = buyers.id
```

So how would I expand on this query now, if I had 3 tables with users: `buyers`, `sellers`, and `administrators`; knowing that the `roleId` column in the `activity` table identifies either a buyer, a seller, or an administrator?

Comment: 3 separate queries with two union statements?

Comment: I would challenge the notion that "merging them is not allowed".  A bad design should not be allowed to propogated just because it is "not allowed" to change it. If you need to do this type of query frequently, then you have a bad design and you should address it.

Comment: I personally am not allowed to make the change, regardless of how bad it is performance-wise or otherwise. It is how it is :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT *, 'Buyer' as accountType FROM activity JOIN buyers b ON activity.userId = b.id 
UNION
SELECT *, 'Seller' FROM activity JOIN sellers s ON activity.userId = s.id 
UNION
SELECT *, 'Admin'  FROM activity JOIN administrators a ON activity.userId = a.id
```

may consider writing the above as a view that way I could build on it as needed, given I can't change any existing table design.

may have to spell out specific table columns as well if buyer, seller, and admin have different columns.  Given you've not provided the table structures, I'm assuming they are identical for this example purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing here as to how roleId relates to the other tables.

```
SELECT * FROM activity JOIN buyers ON activity.userId = buyers.id
WHERE activity.roleId = 1
UNION SELECT * FROM activity JOIN sellers ON activity.userId = sellers.id
WHERE activity.roleId = 2
UNION SELECT * FROM activity JOIN administrators ON activity.userId = administrators.id
WHERE activity.roleId = 3
```